# Invert 2 bit number: is this correct?

Tags: bit-manipulation

I have a 2 bit number `x` stored in a single byte, and I would like to invert it, so that 0 is transformed to 3, 1 to 2, 2 to 1 and 3 to 0.

Is`x^3`be the correct way of doing this?

Also, for arbitrary `N` bit number x, will `x^((1<<N)-1)` be correct ?

Comment: Why not try it out?

Comment: 4 bits numbers range from 0 to 15.

Comment: @AnindyaDutta fixed

Comment: This will work, but you changed the question from N to 1<<N. Might confuse everyone else who comes across this question

Answer (score 4):

x^3 is good for two bit numbers.  If you have 4 bit numbers, use x ^ 15, or write it in hex, x ^ 0x0f if you want.

Answer (score 1):

No, `x^(N-1)` will not work. What will work is `x^(pow(2,N)-1)`

Answer (score 1):

Code :

```
((~x)&(0x3))
```

Test Code (Same piece of code should work in C++ too):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //System.out.println("Hello");

        for(int i=0; i<=3; i++) {
            System.out.println("Complement of " + i + " is " + (~i & 0x3));
        }
    }
```

Result:

```
Complement of 0 is 3
Complement of 1 is 2
Complement of 2 is 1
Complement of 3 is 0
```

Comment: This involves two bit operations, rather than a single x^3, so x^3 would be more efficient.